# React - "'value' prop on 'input' should not be null" for some input but not others

Tags: reactjs

In my React app (version 15.5.4), I am getting the following warning for an input field in one of my components:

`Warning: 'value' prop on 'input' should not be null. Consider using the empty string to clear the component or 'undefined' for uncontrolled components.`

referring to the following jsx:

```
<label>Description<br />
    <input
        type="text"
        name="description"
        value={this.state.group.description}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        maxLength="99" />
</label>
```

But I am perplexed by this, because the value of `this.state.group.description` is set as `""` in my constructor:

```
this.state = {
    "group": {
        "name": "",
        "description": ""
    }
}
```

and furthering my consternation is the fact that another input field refers to `this.state.group.name`, and yet no warning is thrown:

```
<label>Name *<br />
    <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        value={this.state.group.name}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        maxLength="99"
        required="required"
        autoFocus />
</label>
```

Am I missing something here? As far as I can tell, I've set up the initial state of these two values as empty strings and referred to them in the same way in the two input fields, yet one throws a warning and one does not.

It's not the end of the world... the app works fine, but I'd really like to understand why this is happening and get my app running clean.

Here's the `handleChange`:

```
handleChange(event) {
    const attribute = event.target.name
    const updatedGroup = this.state.group
    updatedGroup[attribute] = event.target.value
    this.setState({"group": updatedGroup})
}
```

Comment: Without the parts of your code that changes `this.state.group.description` it's hard to help

Comment: can you post your `handleChange` method

Comment: It may not really be a problem at the time of first load, since the value is an empty string, but there is a chance that you are later modifying it and it becomes null

Comment: @canaanseaton I've added the `handleChange` method

Comment: Oh I think I've figured it out - posting the answer shortly. @ShubhamKhatri thanks - you've pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: you should do `let updatedGroup = Object.assign({}, this.state.group);` instead of `const updatedGroup = this.state.group;`

Comment: @canaanseaton Thanks, you're right. That doesn't fix the problem (see my answer), but yes, that is the best practice.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Thanks to @ShubhamKhatri and @Dekel for pointing me in the right direction on this - I hadn't even considered the fact that the empty string set in the constructor was being overwritten with a problematic value.  It turns out that the source of the issue was that after setting the value of `description` as an empty string, my API was overwriting it with `null`.

I resolved this by tweaking my `render` method like so:

```
let groupDescription;

if (!this.state.group.description) {
    groupDescription = ""
} else {
    groupDescription = this.state.group.description
}

return (
    <label>Description<br />
        <input
            type="text"
            name="description"
            value={groupDescription}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            maxLength="99" />
    </label>
)
```

Comment: So you have options, another solution is  to use the binary operators. E.g. 

`<input value={groupDescription || ""}`.

Comment: That's cool, I never thought to use the binary operators like that. Thanks!

Comment: Readers take care to use `||` *not* `|` which will almost certainly produce unexpected behaviour.  Sincerely: my last 15 minutes

Answer (score 23):

If the value as null then react 15 through the same error. So it's better the default props 'value' of an input should be an empty string in order to run react js code without warning.

```
<input type="text" value={value == null ? '' : value}/>;
```

Comment: It might be better to check for null so that 0 is a valid value. value={value == null ? "" : value}

Comment: Thank you. I had this problem for both `Select` and `TextField` in material UI. That means, it will be problem for both `input` and `textarea` also as above material UI are based on these two.

Comment: This doesn't work very well for input type="number" where the final output should be either null or a number, not an empty string. The only workaround I've found is to do some additional massaging on the data before sending it to my API which is a bit annoying.

Comment: ....in trouble if the value is undefined, not a null value. this is only Half solution.

Answer (score 8):

The problem lies in the handleChange function, you are mutaing the state directly

```
const updatedGroup = this.state.group
updatedGroup[attribute] = event.target.value
```

Use [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to do a clone of the group object

```
handleChange(event) {
    const attribute = event.target.name
    const updatedGroup = [...this.state.group]
    updatedGroup[attribute] = event.target.value
    this.setState({"group": updatedGroup})
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this actually doesn't resolve the issue (see my answer) but you are correct that I wasn't resetting my state appropriately, so +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted the state to be null so I just changed the input's value slightly

```
<input value={someValue ?? ''} onChange={...} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when I hadn't yet added an onChange event handler to the `select` element.

I was just doing an initial test to see how the element looked before adding the onChange event. Unfortunately, I spent too much time trying to figure this out when it wasn't an issue to begin with. The one thing I am not sure of is why it would be reporting it as `null` rather than `""` when an onChange event isn't specified.