# React `value` prop on `input` should not be null

Tags: reactjs, input

I'm new to react and I got this `input` in my component:

```
<input
        type="text"
        placeholder="..."
        className="form-control"
        value={this.state.value}
        disabled={this.props.edit}
        readOnly={this.props.readOnly}
        onChange={(e) => this.state.value = e}
    />
```

Now if `this.state.value` is empty I get this warning:

```
Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.
```

But if I change my input to:

```
<input
        type="text"
        placeholder="..."
        className="form-control"
        value={this.state.value || ""}
        disabled={this.props.edit}
        readOnly={this.props.readOnly}
        onChange={(e) => this.state.value = e}
    />
```

I can't edit it anymore.

Comment: Already addressed the answer to this question.
[Please click the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62160510/8353996)

Answer (score 2):

It should be like -

```
onChange={(e) => this.setState({value:e}) }
```

Comment: `onChange={(e) => this.setState({ value: e.target.value })}` Thats the solution but you got me on the right track, thank you!